# expense of if conditions stored in variables (php)

Tags: php

In php, is this:

```
$ifTrue = ((1 == 1) and (2 == 2));
if ($ifTrue) {
  echo "derp";
}
```

more expensive than this:

```
if ((1 == 1) and (2 == 2)) {
    echo "derp";
}
```

I've taken to storing my conditional expressions in variables to cleanup multi-line if statements.  So far, I have seen no difference in performance.  But my feeling is that because I am reserving a location in memory by doing this, I am gradually eating up memory and, for big scripts, this might be a huge hit to performance that might go undetected.

Follow-up question:  Would there be any difference in expense in other languages such as javascript or perl?

Comment: Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: You are using an extra variable.. that's it, its not going to make a huge different for this code

Comment: you're talking about what will amount to microseconds at best in terms of extra execution time, and unless you're dealing with a facebook-sized php codebase, you are NOT going to run into memory problems by storing a simple int in a variable.

Comment: It's only going to be a memory overhead if your script is one monolithic block of code and you have thousands of such variables, otherwise the variables will drop out of scope as soon as the function they're in terminates, and the memory they used will be flagged for garbage collection.... and if you do have such a monolithic block of code with thousands of such variables, then you have more serious problems with your code than that

Comment: @MarcB `s/unless/even if/`

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, good advice.  The above is only a test scenario.  I only store conditions if there are several lines (i.e. four or more)

Comment: The difference would be some nanoseconds. Go optimize something that matters.

Answer (score 3):

First of: premature optimization will always cause troubles. Don't try to do it if you don't know certain conditions.

Next, your answer depends on circumstances. For example, how many times your expression will be used? Sample: let it be:

```
$foo = very_expensive_function_here();

if($foo)
{
}
//
if($foo && something_else_1())
{
}
//...
if($foo && something_else_1000())
{
}
```

-in this case you'll get extreme increasing of speed since you'll get rid of 1000 expensive function execution times.

But what if your case is just single & simple bool expression? Then it all makes no sense - why use temporary variable at all if you can just evaluate expression on the fly and once?

Comment: "why use temporary variable at all".  readability.  the problem I run into is that sometimes I have if conditions that include several and's and or's and have lots of nested parentheses.